# How to Skip and save the output if no attribute found in bs4

Tags: python, python-3.x

Just want to skip and save the output if "Website_Container" and "Website" atribute not available.

```
for container in containers:

                        path_Website_container = "findAll('a', {'class': 'website-link'})"
                        Path_Website = "[0]['href']"

                        Business_Name = container.h1.text
                        Address = container.h2.text
                        Phone = container.p.text
                                   #want to skip and continue to print if path (value) not found.             

                        Website_container = container.path_Website_container  if path_Website_container else None
                                   #want to skip and continue to print if path (value) not found.             

                        Website = Website_container.Path_Website   if path_Website_container else None
```

Getting this error.

```
    Website = Website_container.Path_Website   if path_Website_container else None
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Path_Website'
```

Comment: `Website = Website_container.Path_Website if Website_container else None`? Also the first letter of your variables should small as per python standards.

Comment: @SwetankPoddar sorry for the mistake it should be Website = Website_container.path_Website   if path_Website else None          - but it's still showing the same problem. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what your code is doing but if you just want to bypass the error:

```
try: 
    # the code
except AttributError:
   pass
```

This here basically says try this code and if I get the attribute error then just ignore it and keep going.